# What's the name of this website component that shows images with right and left arrows?

Tags: website-design

I can't figure out what name is this supposed to have:

[image: We all know this little display-y things]

I am talking about those "featured articles" sections. I just don't know how to google them so I can find some tutorial or guide on how to do one of those. I won't ask that of you, I just want to know the "official name" for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they an official name as such, but some ways to refer to them are 'featured article slider' or maybe just 'article slider' or 'content slider'.

Comment: Agreed – in the source code for the Live Science site, they refer to that section as a "slideshow".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am now on my way to a pretty design :)

And for the detective, Nick, well, I looked at that too, but I didn't get the answer to my problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

A website widget with previous and next arrows powered by JavaScript is usually called a "carousel", "image slider", or "rotating banner".

I would recommend that you *not use them*.   They are [not effective and cause user frustration](http://conversionxl.com/dont-use-automatic-image-sliders-or-carousels-ignore-the-fad/).